# SSMS Server name requires FQDN and won't recognize just the hostname

Tags: sql-server, server, ssms

I am running into an issue where I need to provide FQDN anytime I am entering server names in and it really is bothersome. When I log into SSMS using just the host name, I get a "network-related or instance-specific error". However, when I use the FQDN, it works. What do I need to do to be able to just use hostnames on my machine?

I also work on Power BI reports which points to servers that are not FQDN. So when i make edits and publish, it crashes the gateway due to server name inconsistencies.

Please let me know any quick troubleshooting tips or if you need additional information, i'd be more than happy to provide.

Comment: Nothing to do with SSMS. You need to talk to your network admin. If a name doesn't resolve, that's on them. Also, a gateway doesn't crash due to server name inconsistencies.

Comment: did you try to connect with ip address?

Comment: Oh gotcha... So if it was due to the network, shouldn't other people who are accessing the same server have the same issue? because this is only happening to me...

Comment: yes the ip address works fine but very hard to remember and keep track

Comment: ok then the problem is your hostname could not get resolved. I am posting an answer for your

Comment: "shouldn't other people who are accessing the same server have the same issue?" No, it's a function of the DNS Server you are using and the routers you are traversing to get to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that hostname of your server cannot be resolved. In this case, you can create hostname mapping for your SQL server (which will only work when you are connecting to your SQL server from your computer)

- Open `%WINDIR%\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file with notepad
- at the end of file add your hostname and ip address with the below format
- save and close. Now you are able to connect with the given hostname

example

```
192.168.1.250    sqlserver.local
```